# BSOD occuring after wake Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bsod, nvidia-graphics-card, wake-up, directx

I have a PC running Windows 7 64bits, and Ive had this weird issue since a while. Basically, I noticed that if I put my PC in standby/sleep mode for a (usually) long time(few hours), and then I turn it back on, I am sometimes(I would say maybe 20 or 30% of the time) getting a BSOD as soon as I turn it back on. I never had time to look at the error name(or maybe there isnt one?) but the BSOD occurs always due to the same 3 files/drivers: dxgkrnl.sys and dxgmms1.sys and nvlddmkm.sys . It says that it is caused by the driver dxgkrnl.sys, and file description is Direct X Graphics Kernel. File description of dxgmms1.sys is DirectX Graphics MMS, and nvlddmkm.sys file description is NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver, Version 342.01.My Nvidia graphic card drivers are up to date, as well as most of my drivers on my PC. This is very weird and hard to figure since it rarely happens, but I would like to know if anybody would know why or had a suggestion for me.

Thnak you!

Comment: last nVIDIA driver version is 398.11. so update the GPU driver

Comment: My graphic card is an Nvidia Geforce 8600 GT, and the latest drivers for it is 342.01 and thats what I have

Comment: the 8600 GT is 11 years old, so maybe the card is now damaged. if possible try a different card from a friend and look if the PC is now stable.